# Как сделать чтобы данные сохранённые при отладке в таблице отображались после сборки в *.exe файле?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

Имеется две формы: главная, подчинённая.

**Сценарий**

1. Запускаю отладку;
2. Создаю таблицу `public DataTable dt_1`;
3. Заполняю таблицу через `dataGridView1`;
4. Сохраняю таблицу в `Settings.settings` в переменную `public global::System.Data.DataTable sett_frm_1_dt_1`;
5. Останавливаю отладку;
6. Выполняю сборку проекта;
7. Запускаю файл `rsh.exe` (c:...\rsh\bin\Debug);

**Проблема:** После запуска `rsh.exe` переменная `public global::System.Data.DataTable sett_frm_1_dt_1` пуста.

**Код главной формы**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } // Form1()

        // ФОРМЫ
        Form2 frm_2; // Form2
        public DataTable dt_1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Form2
            frm_2 = new Form2();
            frm_2.Owner = this;
            frm_2.Show();/* или  F2.ShowDialog();*/
        }
    }
```

**Код подчинённой формы**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } // public Form2()

        Form1 frm_1;

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm_1 = this.Owner as Form1; 
            fnk_crt_dt_1();
        }

        private void Form2_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region *** СОБЫТИЯ. f_prt_1.dt_030_html ***
            // Подписываемся на событие вставки новой строки.//
            frm_1.dt_1.TableNewRow += DataTableNewRow; //    
            // СОБЫТИЕ. Происходит после успешного изменения DataRow
            frm_1.dt_1.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed); // 
            // СОБЫТИЕ. Происходит после удаления строки в таблице.
            frm_1.dt_1.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Deleted); // 
            #endregion *** СОБЫТИЯ. f_prt_1.dt_030_html ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ                
            // извлечь таблицу из Settings
            // fnk_frm_1_dt_1_fr_set();
        } // Form2_Show

        // СОБЫТИЕ. ПРИСВОИТЬ ID // 
        private void DataTableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs dataTableNewRowEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                int max = (int)frm_1.dt_1.Compute("Max(ID)", "");
                dataTableNewRowEventArgs.Row["ID"] = max + 1; // dataTableNewRowEventArgs - вызывает событие TableNewRow.
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        // СОБЫТИЕ. Происходит после успешного изменения DataRow
        private void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) //          
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.sett_frm_1_dt_1 = frm_1.dt_1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        // СОБЫТИЕ. Происходит после удаления строки в таблице.        
        private void Row_Deleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
        {   
            Properties.Settings.Default.sett_frm_1_dt_1 = frm_1.dt_1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        // *** *** *** ***
        // ФУНКЦИИ
        // *** *** *** ***

        // создаём таблицу
        public void fnk_crt_dt_1()
        {
            frm_1.dt_1 = new DataTable(); 
            // BS_029_html = new BindingSource();
            frm_1.dt_1.TableName = "frm_1_dt_1_Name";

            // ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ПОЛЕЙ            
            frm_1.dt_1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
            frm_1.dt_1.Columns.Add("pl_1", typeof(String)); // Имя html сценария
            frm_1.dt_1.Columns.Add("pl_2", typeof(String));
            frm_1.dt_1.Columns.Add("pl_3", typeof(String));            

            // добавляем первый 'ID' = 1
            DataRow newRow = frm_1.dt_1.NewRow();
            newRow["ID"] = 1;
            frm_1.dt_1.Rows.Add(newRow);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = frm_1.dt_1;
        }

        public void fnk_frm_1_dt_1_in_set() // сохранить
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.sett_frm_1_dt_1 = frm_1.dt_1;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        public void fnk_frm_1_dt_1_fr_set() // извлечь
        {
            frm_1.dt_1 = Properties.Settings.Default.sett_frm_1_dt_1;            
            dataGridView1.DataSource = frm_1.dt_1;
        }

        // *** *** *** ***
        // КНОПКИ
        // *** *** *** ***

        // создаём таблицу
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fnk_crt_dt_1();
        }

        // сохранить таблицу
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fnk_frm_1_dt_1_in_set();
        }

        // извлечь таблицу
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fnk_frm_1_dt_1_fr_set();
        }

    } // Form2 : Form
```

**ВОПРОС**

1. Как сделать чтобы данные сохранённые при отладке в переменную`public global::System.Data.DataTable sett_frm_1_dt_1` после сборки отображались в `rsh.exe` файле?
2. Также как сделать чтобы данные отображались, если файл `rsh.exe` перемещён в другую папку?

**Скрин**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так это не работает. Нужно проводит сериализацию данных, вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295394/7482894). Да, и между делом по поводу вашего кода, эти ваши ужасные, страхолютные: `frm_2`, `fnk_frm_1_dt_1_in_set()`. Это что-то адовое! Вы шифровку пишете или что? Так нельзя писать. Методы нужно называть с большой буквы, нормальными полными словами, англ. глаголами, т.к. методы что-то делают, а не эти ваши `fnk_` - это вы себе так подсказываете, что это не переменная, а функция?. Локальные переменные с маленькой буквы. Поля классов с маленькой буквы, с нижнем подчеркиванием вначале.

Comment: Плюсанул за гифку. Ожидал скример в конце, был приятно удивлен.

Comment: Вы нажимаете на «Сохранить» (`button2`)? Этот шаг почему-то пропущен. Еще один момент, в вопросе много кода, не относящегося к делу, можно оставить только объявление нужных переменных и сохранение/извлечение таблицы.

Comment: @Bulson `вот пример` - это я первое что попробовал. Но этот пример вроде не выполняет требуемую задачу: чтобы настройки сохранялись начиная от отладки и потом при запуске `*.exe` файла, также при переносе этого файла на другой комп.... Хотя может я что-то не так делаю..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, если два раза запустить программу из Visual Studio то таблица сохраняется и проблема состоит именно в том, что настройки не сохраняются при разном способе запуска (из среды и вручную).

**Проблема**

В папке Debug кроме `rsh.exe` есть еще файл `rsh.vshost.exe`. При откладке из Visual Studio запускается `rsh.vshost.exe`.

Пользовательские  настройки сохраняются в расположении, которое зависит от имени файла. Поэтому для `rsh.exe` и `rsh.vshost.exe` будут разные настройки (что логично для двух разных приложений).

**Сохранение настроек**

Путь, в котором сохраняются пользовательские настройки, для автономного приложения выглядит примерно так:

```
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\(PUBLISHER)\(APP_NAME).exe_(StrongName|Url)_(HASH)\(APP_VERSION)\
```

, по порядку:

- `PUBLISHER`  — организация разработчка, прописывается в настройках проекта;
- `APP_NAME` — имя сборки (в данном случае исполняемого файла);
- `HASH` — хэш строгого имени либо, если его нет, пути;
- `APP_VERSION` — версия, так же прописывается в настройках проекта.

В Вашем случае проблема в том, что при отсутствии строгого имени у сборки хэш рассчитывается по пути к файлу, которое в данном случае будет отличаться.

Подробнее про сохранение пользовательских настроек можно почитать здесь:

- [Client Settings FAQ — MSDN Blogs.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2005/06/29/client-settings-faq/)
- [When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075204/when-using-a-settings-settings-file-in-net-where-is-the-config-actually-stored)

**Решение:**

Как вариант, можно подписать приложение и установить строгое имя. Это можно сделать в Visual Studio (смотрите [руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx)). В этом случае настройки приложения не будут зависеть от расположения файла и `rsh.exe` будет загружать сохраненные настройки после перемещения в другую папку.

**UPDATE:** Как выяснилось, `APP_NAME` это все-таки имя файла, а не имя сборки, соответственно, для `rsh.vshost.exe` настройки будут все-таки разными.

Если очень нужно (интересно, зачем?) чтобы во время отладки использовались те же настройки, то можно отключить создание отдельного исполняемого файла `rsh.vshost.exe`.

В настройках проекта во вкладке «Debug» (скорее всего «Отладка», нет русифицированной среды под рукой) снимите флажок «Enable Visual Studio hosting process» («Разрешить главный процесс Visual Studio»). После этого Visual Studio и во время отладки будет запускать `rsh.exe` напрямую.

Отключение приведет к тому, что отдельные функции во время отладки не будут доступны (подробнее в [руководстве на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms185330.aspx)). Это не должно быть проблемой, можно устанавливать флажок для разработки/отладки и снимать его когда нужна синхронизация настроек.

P.S. Не мог воспроизвести проблему с `vshost.exe` т.к. `APP_NAME` при сохранении настроек обрезается до первых 26 символов. Т.о. если дать приложению длинное название, например, `rsh_WithExtremelyLongName`, то путь к настройкам для `.exe` и `.vshost.exe` совпадет.

Comment: пробую сделать по инструкции предложенной вами `(смотрите руководство)`. Дошёл до `имя модуля`. Сделал: 1. Открыл консоль - `Командная строка разработчика для VS2015`; 2. Перешёл в папку с `rsh.exe` по средствам команды `cd c:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\prb\setting\db\01\rsh\bin\Debug\`; 3. Запустил команду `rsh.exe /target:module Form2.cs`. Согласно инструкции должен появиться файл `*.netmodule`.   У меня его нет. ВОПРОС: может можете подсказать в чём проблема?

Comment: @koverflow не знаю, если честно. Попробуйте подписать без коммандной строки через настройки проекта (пункт «[Создание и подпись сборки строгим именем с помощью Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx#mt10)») этого должно быть достаточно для текущей задачи.

Comment: Предложенное вами решение в пункте `решение` снимает "вопрос 2". Т.е. я: 1. выполнил сборку; 2. Запустил `rsh.exe`; 3. Внес изменения в ДатаТабле + сохранил изменения; 4. Переместил файл `rsh.exe` в другую  папку; 5. Открыл файл `rsh.exe`, загрузил изменения... Это работает.... ВОПРОС. Можно ли сделать, чтобы при `отладке` я внёс изменения, а после `сборки` при запуске файла `rsh.exe`в ДатаТабле отобразилась информация которая заполнялась при `отладке`?

Comment: @koverflow Должно работать и так. Вы пробовали внести изменения в отладке, сохранить их, а затем проверить их через exe-файл?

Comment: `Вы пробовали внести изменения в отладке, сохранить их, а затем проверить их через exe-файл?` - да.. Пока изучаю ваши предложенные вами ссылки.. может  что-то получиться... Прилагаю проект `http://transfiles.ru/ijk9n`. Может я что-то не то делаю

Comment: @koverflow да, кажется, для достижения такого эффекта нужно будет отключить `vshost.exe`. Я дописал ответ, посмотрите обновление.

Comment: `Если очень нужно (интересно, зачем?)` -  в таблице(или в других источниках) находятся данные, которые имеют отношение к работе программы. Данные в таблицу вносятся пользователем.. Программу отладил, собрал проект. Запускаю `rsh.exe`,  таблица пустая... и приходится снова заполнять.. А так пользователь получает уже настроенную программу.. PS. Пока опыта маловато, так, что делаю так...